# How to find strings and put them in a list only once in python?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have some strings in a list like:

```
a =
[
  'Android'
  'Android.Browser'
  'Android.Browser.Url'
  'Android.Messaging'
  'Futureshop'
  'Futureshop.Filter'
  'Futureshop.Filter.Hello'
  'Futureshop.Test'
  'Test'
  'Test.Hello'
]
```

What I want to do is, get the first names of all these strings (Android, Futureshop, Test) only once and put them in a list. The list would then look like:

```
b = ['Android', 'Futureshop', 'Test']
```

i.e; it should not contain any string more than once.

**EDIT/NOTE:** I didn't know of using sets in python previously. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Have you heard of sets?

Comment: The data structure for that is a set.

Comment: You need ``set``, ``str.split`` and ``list``.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not getting the solution. I just get all the strings like Android 4 times, Futureshop 4 times and Test 2 times

Comment: @Wooble How do I use that?

Comment: @Sazid https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well assuming they are in a list as follows:

```
a = ['Android',
'Android.Browser',
'Android.Browser.Url',
'Android.Messaging',
'Futureshop',
'Futureshop.Filter',
'Futureshop.Filter.Hello',
'Futureshop.Test',
'Test',
'Test.Hello']
```

You can do it as:

```
b = list(set(i.split('.', 1)[0] for i in a ))

>>> print b
['Test', 'Android', 'Futureshop']
```

Comment: `i.split('.', 1)[0]` ;-)